# Let $a,b,z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a>0$ and $z_1-z_2=a-1$. Prove that there is a unique $r$ and $q$ with $b=aq+r$ and $z_1≤r≤z_2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,z_1,z_2  \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a>0$ and $z_2-z_1=a-1$. Prove that there is a unique $r$ and $q$ with $b=aq+r$ and $z_1≤r≤z_2$.

Please help! 
How do I prove $z_1≤r≤z_2$,and $S$ is not an empty set (but I am not sure how to set $S$)?. 
And can I rewrite $z_1≤r≤z_2$ in different terms?

Comment: Can you use that $b=aq'+r'$ where $0\le r' \le a-1$ ?

Comment: $z_1 \ge z_2$, hence the condition on $r$ should be $z_2 \le r \le z_1$.

Comment: @lhf You mean for general division algorithm? I am not sure. My prof. said this is a generalization of the division algorithm though. If I could use that, I do I make connection with $z_1≤r≤z_2$ using $z_1−z_2=a−1$?

Comment: @njguliyev Sorry, mistyped.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints:* One of the numbers $b-z_2, b-z_2+1, \ldots, b-z_1$ is divisible by $a$ and $aq_1+r_1 - (aq_2+r_2) = a(q_1-q_2) + (r_1-r_2)$.

Comment: I need more explanation.

Comment: $b-z_2 + 1 = b-z_1 + a$, hence when you divide by $a$ the remainders of the numbers in my answer obtain all possible values. So one of them is divisible by $a$.

Comment: My initial answer and first comment were for the case $z_1 \ge z_2$, but since you changed that condition, I edited my answer.

Comment: I am totally lost. How about this. I just tried to prove the way I did in the class. Let S={$x\in \mathbb{W}: x=b-aq$ for some $q\in \mathbb{Z}$ Prove that S is not an empty set.Case 1) $0≤b$. Let $q=0$. $x=b-a0$, $x=b$ so non empty.Case 2) $0>b$. Let $q=-1$. $x=b-a(-1)$, $x=b+a$. $b+a$ is positive, so non empty set. Does it make sense?